# AngularJS $scope not accessible in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, scope, directive

As the title summaries pretty well, I've got a template where it seems impossible to access my $scope. To write some more information. The template is rendered into a directive from another template like this:

```
<site-overview class="site-overview float_left" ng-repeat="site in currentEngine.data.sites" site='site' provider='currentEngine' style="background-color: {{currentEngine.data.skin.skin_color_2}}">
  </site-overview>
```

These 'site-overview' templates are visible, but when I try to access the variable, site, that I add to the scope in the template, I simply can't even though when I log the variable, I get the data in my console, like this:

```
    (function(){
  'use strict';
  var singleSiteOverview = angular.module('stormforsStats.siteoverview',[]);

  singleSiteOverview.directive("siteOverview", [function(){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        site:'=',
        provider: '='
      },
      templateUrl: "parts/pages/home/site-overview/site_overview.html",
      controller: 'siteOverviewCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'site'
    };
  }]);

  singleSiteOverview.controller('siteOverviewCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$log', '$element', 'SERVER_DATA',
  function($rootScope, $scope, $log, $element, SERVER_DATA){
    $log.log($scope.site);
  }]);
})();
```

So this log works perfectly, but in the template I can't access $root:

```
    <a href="http://{{site.host_name}}" target="_blank" alt="site not available">
  <h4 class="skin_main_color">{{site.site_name}}</h4>
</a>
```

For your information, I didn't include all code here, only the code related to the problem (for as far as I know).

This doesn't work.

Comment: You are using 'controller as' so {{site.site_name}} is referring to a property 'site_name' on your controller but you don't have such a property.

Comment: yes, that was it! Been staring at this way too long. Just a duplicate -.- Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the comments suggested, because you are using "controller as", your isolate scope variable is binding to the scope, and not to your controller, which I'm guessing is why you can't access it from your template.

Here is a similar problem as an issue on github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7635